# React dropdown function triggers all dropdowns instead of selected menu

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to figure out how to only trigger the dropdown for the selected menu. Right now if I click on any of my menu items, it triggers every single dropdown.

I currently have a simple function that sets the state from false to true

```
   const showSubnav = () => setSubnav(!subnav);
```

I attempted to use `useRef()` but for some reason the `ref.current` kept showing the wrong element that I clicked on.

Here is my current dropdown code

```
 {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <>
              <li
                ref={ref}

                // Here's the function that checks if there's a sub menu, then it triggers 
               showSubnav

                onClick={item.subNav && showSubnav}


                key={index}
                className={item.cName}
              >
                <Link to={item.path}>
                  {item.icon}
                  <span>{item.title}</span>
                </Link>
              </li>
              {subnav ? (
                <>
                  {item.subNav &&
                    item.subNav.map((item, index) => {
                      return (
                        <div key={index} className='sub-nav-container'>
                          <Link to={item.path} className={item.cName}>
                            {item.icon}
                            <span>{item.title}</span>
                          </Link>
                        </div>
                      );
                    })}
                </>
              ) : null}
            </>
          );
        })}
```

So the issue is that any `li` with a sub menu will display if I click on it using my code

```
   onClick={item.subNav && showSubnav}
```

I need a function or way to check for the current element clicked and to only trigger that sub menu for that specific element.

I also have react icons that I used in my data file

So I'm trying to display them only if there's a sub nav

This code is the logic, but I can't seem to fit it anywhere properly

```
  if(item.subNavExists) {
 {item.downArrow}
 } else if(subnav is click) {
 {item.upArrow}
 }
 else {
  return null
  }
```

How would I fit this logic inside of my li tags?

```
    <Link to={item.path}>
      {item.icon}

     
      <span>{item.title}</span>
    </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach,

Create a separate component for `Sidebar` and track each sidebar changes separately using local state like below,

```
import { Link } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const SidebarData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Item1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Item2"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
        return <Sidebar item={item} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const Sidebar = ({ item }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div class="container">
      <button onClick={() => setSelected(!selected)}>
        {selected ? "hide" : "show"}
      </button>
      <li key={item.id} className={item.cName}>
        <Link to={item.path}>
          {item.icon}
          <span>{item.title}</span>
        </Link>
      </li>
      {selected && <div>SUB-NAV</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Sample demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-booth-mj9xo?file=/src/App.js

Comment: your data file doesn't have any sub menus included in it though

Comment: I have put the placeholder for that. You can include the submenu in the place of `SUB-NAV`

Comment: I have placed a button for showing and hiding sub-menus

Comment: ah okay I think i got it. My issue is how would I display a down arrow and up arrow by clicking? I can show the icons, but I only want my icons to show if it contains a sub menu. I updated my question with my example logic I'm trying to implement above

Comment: let me know anything i need to update in the codebase. I have captured all in highlevel.

Comment: the icon part is what I need to complete it, but I can't figure out how to implement it with your code. How would you add a up and down arrow based on the sub menu clicked or not? Also, how would you prevent the up and down arrow from showing on menus that don't have any dropdown?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225188/discussion-between-sarun-uk-and-johnxr).